# SSRS report subscriptions cannot be created

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string, ssrs-2008

I am not able to create subscriptions for SSRS reports as it gives the following error:

> Subscriptions cannot be created because the credentials used to run
>   the report are not stored, or if a linked report, the link is no
>   longer valid.

**My set up is as following:**

ServerA - Database Server

ServerB - Report Server

MachineC - Internet explorer to view the reports

So I am viewing reports on Machine C, IE, and ServerB connects to ServerA for Datasource.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem sounds like the report expects the user to provide credentials when it is viewed. When you create a subscription, it does not have the credentials to execute the report.

Go to the report, click the properties tab, then choose Data Sources in the left pane.

Are you using a shared data source? Is it using Windows integrated security? If so, can you change it to use a service account made just to run these reports? You may need to view these properties by viewing the data source itself.

If it is a custom data source is the option "Credentials supplied by the user running the report" selected? If so, can you change it to "Credentials stored securely in the report server"?

Either way, if you want to set up a subscription, I have made it work by providing credentials in the data source rather than have the user input them.

If you are worried about security, I would suggest managing that on the report level rather than the data source level.

Comment: thanks , it works after storing the credentials in shared data source

Comment: If your report uses sub-reports also ensure that the sub-reports are using the data source with saved credentials, otherwise it won't let you create a subscription on the parent report.

Answer (score 3):

What the error does not make clear is, in order to be able to subscribe to a report not only must the data source be set to "Credentials stored securely in the report server" you must also not select the option "Impersonate the authenticated user after a connection has been made to the data source".

Answer (score 2):

The way I did was to create a new data source in the report builder and explicitly provided the username and password there to be used.
Then, used that username password with the new data source with the report and voila it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as you, and i found its solution, as @richard said already that it is related to credential of data source you use for your deployed report.
To resolve it Follow these steps:
1. Right click on your shared Data source which you use in your deployed report.
2. Click On Edit Button.
3. a new window will open click on Credential from left pane, Select Use this user name and password then click ok.
4. Check on Save these credential option you get on to previous screen.
5. Test connection and if succeed click ok and deploy your project on report server.

For reference plese look at screen shot given below:
[image: Datasource credentioal screen]

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest setting up a service account if you are going to go this route rather than using the sa password. Some SQL server installations go without using an sa account. More importantly, creating a service account - something like serviceReportViewer - will let you limit the permissions of that account to only what's needed to view reports. It's an unnecessary risk use the sa account since its permission levels are so high.